# Is square of Poisson kernel conditionally convergent?

Tags: harmonic-functions, conditional-convergence, summability-theory

Poisson kernel is defined for $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ as
$$P_r(\theta) = \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}$$
which equals
$$P_r(\theta) = \frac{1-r^2}{r^2-2r\cos (\theta) + 1 }.$$
For this second expression, clearly for all $\theta\neq 0, \ P_r^2(\theta)$ tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to $1$. But calculating  the same for the first expression gives
\begin{eqnarray}
&P_r(\theta)&=\sum\limits_{n_1\in\mathbb{Z}}r_1^{|n_1|}e^{in_1\theta}\sum\limits_{n_2\in\mathbb{Z}}r_2^{|n_2|}e^{in_1\theta}
\\&&=\sum\limits_{n_1\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum\limits_{n_2\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{|n_1|+|n_2|}e^{i(n_1+n_2)\theta}
\end{eqnarray}
Let $\theta\neq 0$ and observe
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \ r^{|n|+|-n|}e^{i(n-n)\theta}=r^{|2n|}.$$
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
&P_r^2(\theta )&=\sum\limits_{(n_1,n_2)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}r^{|n_1|+|n_2|}e^{i(n_1+n_2)\theta}
\\&&=\sum\limits_{
(n_1,n_2)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}
\\ n_1\neq - n_2
}r^{|n_1|+|n_2|}e^{i(n_1+n2)\theta}
+
\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{|2n|}e^{i(n-n)\theta}
\\&&=\sum\limits_{
(n_1,n_2)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}
\\ n_1\neq - n_2
}r^{|n_1|+|n_2|}e^{i(n_1+n2)\theta}
+
\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{|2n|}
\end{eqnarray}
In the last line the second term is a geometric sequence and converges to $2/(1-r^2)-1$, which diverges (for all $\theta$) as $r$ tends to $1$. This makes me think Is the square of Poisson kernel conditionally convergent?

Comment: first of all, without looking at any of your work, since Poisson kernel is absolutely convergent, its square is absolutely convergent. second, looking at your work, the term $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} r^{|2n|}$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Indeed, that term is a geometric sequence and converges to $1/(1-r^2)$, which diverges (for all $\theta$) as $r$ tends to $1$.

Comment: I don't think you know what "absolutely convergent" means

Comment: I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Let me clarify. Clearly the series converges absolutely (and therefore unconditionally) for $r<1$, but for $r=1$ the second term of the last line $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} r^{|2n|}$ diverges, and thus **for $r=1$** the series seem to be conditionally convergent. If the issue is not clear please let me know.

Comment: Okay, I don't know why you were talking about $r$ converging to $1$. You want to see what happens at $r=1$. At $r=1$, the sum $\sum_{(n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}} |r^{|n_1|+|n_2|} e^{i(n_1+n_2)\theta}| = \sum_{(n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}} 1$ diverges, so the series corresponding to $P_r^2(\theta)$ is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: At $r=1$, $\sum_{(n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}} r^{|n_1|+|n_2|}e^{i(n_1+n_2)\theta} = \sum_{(n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}} e^{i(n_1+n_2)\theta}$. As you should know, for conditionally convergent series, the order in which you sum is important to specify. So can you please specify the order in which you sum over $(n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ in the series associated to $P_r^2(\theta)$?